# Exclude model from an included jar

Tags: java, gradle

gradle looks like:

```
dependencies{
compile files('libs/myJarContainingGuava.jar')
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
}
```

myJarContainingGuava has an old guava version in it.

My current code is picking that jar instead of picking the guava 18.

I cannot modify myJarContainingGuava.jar

Comment: does myJarContainingGuava.jar contain more than just guava? otherwise just remove this file dependency!

Comment: ya it contains a lot of files who are dependent on guava

Comment: you could (as part of the build) repackage the myJarContainingGuava into another file and exclude the guava dependencies.

Comment: you could also try to change the dependency order. but be careful as order might not be guaranteed in your project and is general considered to be bad practice.